# Win Azure: Flash Player playing Video hosted in BLOB storage

Tags: flash, azure, video-streaming, blob

I'm pretty unfamiliar with video streaming. Does anyone know of a page that gives an example of all the steps involved in setting up a web page to stream a video from blob storage? Ideally using FLASH player, not silverlight.

I have a website in Azure that has a page with flash player.  It works just fine if I include the MP4 video file in the VS project folder, but if I change the file name to the URL of the same video file in BLOB storage, I get a blank display.  Videos are made and provided by my client, so I don't control formats, etc.

In my web page I have the following object tag:

```
    <object id="csSWF" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="704" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
        <param name="movie" value="VideoFileName_controller.swf" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="tocdoc=left&amp;showsearch=true&amp;autostart=false&amp;autohide=true&amp;xmp=VideoFileName_config.xml&amp;content=https://BLAHBLAHBLAH.blob.core.windows.net/media/VideoFileName.mp4&amp;thumb=FirstFrame.png&amp;containerwidth=800&amp;containerheight=704&amp;smoothing=true&amp;enablejsapi=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;windowbox=false&amp;showbranding=false&amp;showstartscreen=true&amp;showendscreen=true&amp;basecolor=272727&amp;loop=false" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="VideoFileName_controller.swf" width="800" height="704">
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="tocdoc=left&amp;showsearch=true&amp;autostart=false&amp;autohide=true&amp;xmp=VideoFileName_config.xml&amp;content=https://BLAHBLAHBLAH.blob.core.windows.net/media/VideoFileName.mp4&amp;thumb=FirstFrame.png&amp;containerwidth=800&amp;containerheight=704&amp;smoothing=true&amp;enablejsapi=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;windowbox=false&amp;showbranding=false&amp;showstartscreen=true&amp;showendscreen=true&amp;basecolor=272727&amp;loop=false" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div id="noUpdate">
                <p>The video content presented here requires JavaScript to be enabled in your browser and the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player installed. If you are using a browser with JavaScript disabled please enable it now. Otherwise, please update your version of the free Adobe Flash Player by <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">downloading here</a>. </p>
            </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->                    
        </object> 
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
```

Comment: I am able to get a simple case working:         <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='https://SampleURL.net/media/Sample.swf' width='100%' height='590'>
            <param name='movie' value='https://SampleURL.net/media/Sample.swf' />
        </object>    So apparently this is more of an issue with Flash and how the above video is configured than it is Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a wrong content type. You should try changing the content type of your MP4 file to **video/mp4**.

See the following blog post for more information: [Why it is important to set proper content-type HTTP header for blobs in Azure Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/04/04/why-it-is-important-to-set-proper-content-type-http-header-for-blobs-in-azure-storage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Flash does not support downloading data from non-http urls.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60132

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I used http: rather than https: it would work?

Comment: Sorry, I read your exact blob URL now, I had confused it with html5 blob storage. Since you do not mention crossdomain file, I feel there might be trouble with a different domain name. [Cross-domain Loading Restrictions](http://www.dwuser.com/flashslideshow/v4/help/advanced_topics/understanding_flash_player_cross_domain_loading_restrictions.html)